# Problem with files in External Hard Disk

Tags: external-hdd, data-loss, fat32, hidden-files

While making my USB bootable for the installation of UBUNTU using Disk Startup Tool in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the process was cancelled and disconnected my external hard disk from the laptop(The source file (.iso) was in the external hard disk). When connected back, it shows neither files nor folders which was already in HD, but only few files with unknown format. Its names are seen as Greek letters.

When I checked in Windows, the total used memory space of the Drive shows unchanged, but memory of files show ‘zero bytes’.

For information:-
External HD: 1 TB My Passport Ultra
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Laptop: Dell Inspiron N4050

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: specify the filesystem type, whether it is ntfs or fat32 or something else.

Comment: file system is fat32

Comment: This may be a corrupted file system. What does `fsck` have to say about it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the data has been corrupted somehow.

From your Ubuntu 12.04, try running a `fsck` on the external drive.

Install `Dosfsck` with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install dosfstools`

Find the partition you want to 'repair' with `mount`. Then `unmount` the partition by running
`sudo umount /dev/sdc1`
(replacing `/dev/sdc1` with the mount point of your device).

Then you can verify and repair the partition with
`sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sdc1`

(replacing `/dev/sdc1` with the mount point of your device).

If this fails to repair the partition, you can try recovering the files from the partition with a utility such as `TestDisk`. Which you can read more about here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: I get these messages when I run the above commands:"fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 -t and -w require -a or -r". What does it mean?

Comment: Basil, did you run 'sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sdc1' (with the correct device of course)? The message you're getting means it's missing the -a argument.